# Regular expression in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

how to check particular value start with string or digit. here i attached my code. am getting error to like idendifier expected.

```
code
----
 Dim i As String
 dim ReturnValue  as boolean
    i = 400087
    Dim s_str As String = i.Substring(0, 1)

   Dim regex As Regex = New Regex([(a - z)(A-Z)])
    ReturnValue = Regex.IsMatch(s_str, Regex)




error 

regx is type and cant be used as an expression
```

Comment: If Regex isnt a must - and it seems a bit like overkill to use regex here - you could simply use `if Char.IsLetterOrDigit(TheString(0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is `regex`, `Regex` is the type of the variable.

So it is:

```
ReturnValue = Regex.IsMatch(s_str, regex)
```

But your regex is also flawed. `[(a - z)(A-Z)]` is creating a character class that does exactly match the characters `()-az`, the range `A-Z` and a space and nothing else.

It looks to me as if you want to match letters. For that just use `\p{L}` that is a Unicode property that would match any character that is a letter in any language.

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[\p{L}\d]")
```

Comment: Note the letter *or digit at the start* in the Q... otherwise you've almost got it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean

```
Dim _regex As Regex = New Regex("[(a-z)(A-Z)]")
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Dim regex As Regex = New Regex([(a - z)(A-Z)])
> ReturnValue = Regex.IsMatch(s_str, Regex)
> ```

Note case difference, use `regex.IsMatch`. You also need to quote the regex string: `"[(a - z)(A-Z)]"`.

---

Finally, that regex doesn't make sense, you are matching any letter or opening/closing parenthesis anywhere in the string.

To match at the start of the string you need to include the start anchor `^`, something like: `^[a-zA-Z]` matches any ASCII letter at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Check if a string starts with a **letter** or **digit**:

```
ReturnValue = Regex.IsMatch(s_str,"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

Regex Explanation:

```
^           # Matches start of string
[a-zA-Z0-9] # Followed by any letter or number
+           # at least one letter of number
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/M4Y7ZHKme1).